# Moving files from Subfolders into root directory, but not copying them to the next directory when ran again

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder that contains subfolders with MP4 files. I'm trying to write a script that will move the MP4 files out of the subfolders into the root folder when ran. The batch file I wrote is working, but when the batch script runs again for new subfolders, the MP4 files that were already copied to the root folder, get moved up another level in the file structure. For example:

```
C:\MainRoot\Root\Subfolder\media.mp4
```

When script is ran, 'media.mp4' gets moved up to C:\Root\media.mp4 as desired.
But since I need the script to run on a scheduled task. The next time the script runs I get the following:

```
C:\MainRoot\media.mp4
```

Instead of just the MP4 file staying in C:\MainRoot\Root.
Here's my batch file so far to copy the mp4 files:

```
set root_folder=C:\MainRoot\Root
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%G in ('dir %root_folder% /b /o:-n /s ^| findstr /i ".mp4" ') do (
move /y "%%G" "%%~dpG..\%%~nxG"
)
```

What do I need to modify so that once moved, the MP4 files will stay in place?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your source files seem to be at a certain directory level, a `for /D` loop could be wrapped around your `for /F` loop, which parses the output of a non-recursive `dir` command line (no `/S`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\MainRoot\Root"
set "_PATTERN=*.mp4"

rem // Loop through sub-directories:
for /D %%D in ("%_ROOT%\*") do (
    rem // Loop through matching files:
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%%~fD\%_PATTERN%"') do (
        rem // Avoid overwriting destination file:
        if not exist "%_ROOT%\%%~nxF" (
            rem // Move matching file one level up:
            move /Y "%%~fD\%%~nxF" "%_ROOT%\%%~nxF"
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this- when I try to run it, nothing occurs. I just get another command line prompt, and no files were moved... any ideas? I copied it and pasted it and change just the root folder constant.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, stupid me, I referenced the files wrongly; I fixed it now -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40389031/2)...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One last question- let's say a folder is being uploaded to the server's folder and the large MP4 file isn't finished being written when this bat file runs and attempts to move it. What would you think would happen? I would presume Windows would keep writing the file after it's been moved, but I suppose I need to test that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to overwrite as in your provided example then something as simple as this may suit your purpose:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set root_folder=C:\MainRoot\Root
If /I NOT "%CD%"=="%root_folder%" PushD "%root_folder%" 2>Nul||Exit/B
For /R %%G In (*.mp4) Do If /I NOT "%~dpG"=="%root_folder%\" Move "%%G">Nul 2>&1
```

If the files are only one folder deep you may prefer this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set root_folder=C:\MainRoot\Root
If /I NOT "%CD%"=="%root_folder%" PushD "%root_folder%" 2>Nul||Exit/B
For /D %%G In (*) Do Move "%%G\*.mp4">Nul 2>&1
```